# Is there an efficient way to retrieve values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of values. This is for a company name.

It has 3 keys:

> ```
> {'html_attributions': [],
>  'result' : {'Address': '123 Street', 'website' :'123street.com' 
>  'status': 'Ok' }
> ```

I have a dataframe of many dictionaries. I want to loop through each row's dictionary and get the necessary information I want.

Currently I am writing for loops to retrieve these information. Is there a more efficient way to retrieve these information?

```
addresses = []
for i in range(len(testing)):
    try:
        addresses.append(testing['Results_dict'][i]['result']['Address'])
    except:
        addresses.append('No info')
```

What I have works perfectly fine. However I would like something that would be more efficient. Perhaps using the get() method? but I don't know how I can call to get the inside of 'result'.

Comment: `testing['Results_dict'][i]['result'].get('Address', 'No info')`?

Comment: @Timus right that works! Thanks. Also is there another way to loop through this without a for loop? Since I need to loop for each row i'm not sure how it would work without a for loop

Comment: Read the **2**. answer here: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). Here you could either use `apply()` or do a list comprehenison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_address(r):
    try:
        return r['result']['Address']
    except Exception:
        return 'No info'

addresses = df['Results_dict'].map(get_address)
```

This guards against cases where `Result_dict` is None, not a dict, or any key along the path way does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a way faster solution if the data is big:

```
addresses = list(map(lambda x: x.get('result').get('Address', 'No info'), testing['Results_dict']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I deal with nested dict keys:

Example:

```
def keys_exists(element, *keys):
    if not isinstance(element, dict):
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects dict as first argument.')
    if len(keys) == 0:
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects at least two arguments, 
              one given.')

    _element = element
    for key in keys:
    try:
        _element = _element[key]
    except KeyError:
        return False
return True
```

For data :

```
{'html_attributions': [],
 'result' : {'Address': '123 Street', 'website' :'123street.com' 
 'status': 'Ok' }
```

if you want to check result exists or not use above function like this

```
`print 'result (exists/Not): {}'.format(keys_exists(data,"result"))`
```

To check address exist inside result Try this

```
`print 'result > Address (exists/not): {}'.format(keys_exists(data, "result", "Address"))`
```

It will return output in True/False